# routing with express and es6 but got a TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, router

im using express and es6 and im trying to route in this way..

index.js

```
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import appRoutes from './routes/appRoutes.js'

var app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api', appRoutes);
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send("hellow  express"));
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server runing on port : http://localhost:${PORT}`));
```

appRoutes.js

```
import express from 'express'
import {hello, sendMessage} from '../controllers/appController.js'
const appRoutes = express.Router();

appRoutes.get('/', hello);
appRoutes.post('/', sendMessage);

export default {appRoutes};
```

but run through this error.....
Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in appRoutes.js file, change this

```
export default {appRoutes};
```

into

```
export default appRoutes;
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try to redo importing and exporting in a similar way:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Only I think you don't need to pass and handle the db variable like I do